# Nozzle geometry WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, shapes

I'm currently doing a CFD simple problem with C# in WPF analyzing a quasi-one-dimensional flow (only varying with x) and I want to represent the results in a "decent" way. Hence, imagine it as a rectangle with a given number of vertical sections. The form is not a rectangle, but a nozzle. What I was wondering is if there is a way of representing with Stackpanels or something similar a certain form.

In the image attached the shape can be seen, to help understand the problem.

Every section (a rectangle "cut" by the edges of the nozzle) has a temperature associated and already computed.Just to give an example, a temperature value of 250 for the section drawn, and for example I want to paint it with a Red color.

**My question is: Is there any way of "shaping" stackpanels or something similar to display something like the shape shown?**

I've searched for information and this is the most similar option found:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
      <PathGeometry.Figures>
        <PathFigureCollection>
          <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100">
            <PathFigure.Segments>
              <PathSegmentCollection>
                <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="200,200" Point2="300,100" />
              </PathSegmentCollection>
            </PathFigure.Segments>
          </PathFigure>
        </PathFigureCollection>
      </PathGeometry.Figures>
    </PathGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Which draws this image. What I would like to construct is the nozzle with this method and be able to divide it or place vertical segments inside it as suggested at the first image, painting them according to the value they have.
[image]
[image: Description of the problem]

[image: Sketch]

Comment: As stated, this question is far too broad at best and, really, not clear at all. Why does `StackPanel` even have any relevance to the goal? What have you tried so far? What did that code do? How was that different from what you wanted it to do? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly answers these questions. I would think a `GeometryDrawing` or similar would suit this task better than a `StackPanel`, by far.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've updated the post with what I have tried so far. Hope it is easier to understand now :)

Comment: Please see the link I provided for information on what is meant by [mcve]. Note that you can draw filled shapes using geometry as well. I still don't see why one would use a `StackPanel` here.

Comment: Eh don't dwell on the semantics of the StackPanel use case, I'm sure the dude may just not have thought of the right nomenclature. Anyway, yes you could do an actually pretty nifty display like this using some path geometry, potentially drawing brush, and opacity masks but it's one of those things you'll probably have trouble finding someone to donate the time to do in full solution since it would likely take some tinkering to get the desired result. Neat concept though!

Comment: @PeterDuniho I don't need to use a StackPanel. I would love to write a full example but I do not know how to draw the geometry. I have drawn it in a paper to show what I want to do and updated my post. First of all, create the outer geometry, and then create inner sub-geometries that will be filled according to a colormap, but it is a complex geometry (containing even more inside) and I'm not capable of doing it, that's why I'm asking it.

Comment: If you don't need to use `StackPanel`, then I would remove all mention of it from your question if I were you. It's just a distraction. As for the problem generally, you should look at the `CombinedGeometry` type. With it, you can combine the nozzle shape (you'll probably need a closed version, in addition to the opened one you're actually drawing) and the vertical rectangle with an intersection operator to get the vertical shape you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a pretty complex problem which may be too much for a single SO question. By no means am I providing a complete solution to your problem. But maybe it will be enough to point you in the right direction. From there, you can start on your own solution and ask further questions if you get stuck.

Your best solution is probably to manually draw shapes on the canvas using c# (or possibly XAML).

Here's the best link I could find after a quick search.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808(v=vs.100).aspx

It is a Microsoft tutorial of drawing Geometry and Geometric Shapes in XAML and code.
See the section about path geometries. 
I would think that by combining two ArcSegments for the curved sides and LineSegments connecting the two sides that you could get the basic shape you are looking for.

I think that for your rectangular "cuts", you will have to build those explicitly in code as well. It will be tricky to match their shape exactly when overlaying them over the nozzle. One simple work around could be to create all your horizontal bars and paint them. Then create a top and a bottom white overlay that covers up the rectangles. One overlay would have the shape of the top nozzle and cover the parts of the rectangles you don't want shown. And similarly for another shape that makes up the bottom of the nozzle.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was looking for :)

I can try to drow the outer shape with the geometry tutorial but the main problem are the vertical cuts. Do you have any idea of how to draw rectangles overpassing the boundaries and then place something at a "higher" layer (for instance, a black background) to make this small parts of the rectangle not visible by overwriting them?

Comment: I believe the z axis (depth of shapes) is controlled by the order in which the shapes are drawn. So the first item drawn would be covered by the second item drawn if they overlap. So draw all the rectangles first. Then draw the matte shape next. It will overlay on top of the rectangles hiding the edges.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll give it a try :)